# Multichannel Mixer + Voice-Processing IO Unit

Tags: core-audio, voip, audiounit, mixer, remoteio

I have an AUGraph setup and working, it consists of a multichannel mixer (with a single monophonic input) feeding a RemoteIO (`kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO`) unit to output to the speaker. I implemented the single input mixer in order to be able to pan my audio source between Left and Right hardware output channels. This works just fine.

As this is a VOIP application, I have been experimenting with using a Voice-processing IO Unit (`kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO`) in place of the Remote IO Unit (`kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO`). Per Apple's description, this unit should behave like a Remote IO unit with some extra features...

> The Voice-Processing I/O unit (subtype `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO`) has the characteristics of the Remote I/O unit and adds echo suppression for two-way duplex communication. It also adds automatic gain correction, adjustment of voice-processing quality, and muting. This is the correct I/O unit to use for VoIP (Voice over Internet Protocol) apps.

But I am noting that when I switch to the Voice Processing IO Unit, I lose the ability to pan using the mixer. Any ideas as to what is going on here? Is the Voice Processing IO Unit inherently monophonic?

Comment: What are your stream formats? I don't think the VP I/O unit is inherently monphonic

Comment: The mixer input has the following format:        AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat = { 0 };
        
        audioFormat.mSampleRate   = 16000.00;
        audioFormat.mFormatID   = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        audioFormat.mFormatFlags  = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
        audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
        audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel  = 16;
        audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket  = 2;
        audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame  = 2;

Comment: okay, that looks right. If you have the code on github/gist I can take a look, but its hard to see what's happenning without more context or info. Like what does *losing ability to pan* mean? Is there an error thrown or panning just stops working?

Comment: Regarding "losing the ability to pan"... using RemoteIO gives me a stereo signal to the headphones which responds to Left/Right balance adjustments, either at the multi-channel mixer or the iOS/Settings/General/Accessibility/Balance slider. When I simply switch the subtype to the VPIO unit, the signal no longer responds to the balance adjustment. The signal appears to be equal in Left/Right channels independent of balance (aka panning) and so I assumed the output must be monophonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my particular AUGraph, a Multichannel Mixer Output feeding the IO Unit, dumping the ASBD for the input scope of the IO Unit always shows 2 channels per frame. As I understand from the documentation, the Multichannel Mixer's output is stereo.

I dumped the ASBD for the output scope of the RemoteIO unit and indeed the ASBD shows 2 channels per frame. Trying to overwrite this to 1 channel resulted in a kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotWritable error.

Then I switched the subtype to the VPIO unit. Dumping the ASBD for the output scope shows 1 channel per frame. And as above, trying to overwrite this to 2 channels also resulted in the same property-not-writable error.

So at least for my particular AUGraph , I must conclude that the VPIO unit is inherently monophonic.

Comment: It really is unfortunate, as the VPIO unit is the only thing that works well for echo cancellation